# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement [subdependency]>[version] (from [subdependency]) (from versions: none)

Tags: python, installation, pip, packaging, pypi

I've built and uploaded my package to TestPyPI with poetry, and now face this error when installing my package in a fresh virtual environment.

```bash
❯ pip3 install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ my-package==0.1.0
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting my-package==0.1.0
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/e4/0dee9b9d0606f5413256b84a8df84d9ba416c99c51885827e6d5a90a29ea/my_package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4<5.0.0,>=4.11.1
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/d8/909c4089dbe4ade9f9705f143c9f13f065049a9d5e7d34c828aefdd0a97c/beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 128.2/128.2 kB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting requests
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/00/8ed1b6ea43b10bfe28d08e6af29fd6aa5d8dab5e45ead9394a6268a2d2ec/requests-2.5.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (468 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 468.9/468.9 kB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting fire
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/07/a119a1aa04d37bc819940d95ed7e135a7dcca1c098123a3764a6dcace9e7/fire-0.4.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 87.7/87.7 kB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of standup-shows to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement soupsieve>1.2 (from beautifulsoup4) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for soupsieve>1.2
```

Here's what my `pyproject.toml` looks like:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-package"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "My description."
authors = ["My Name"]
license = "GPL-3.0-or-later"
readme = "README.md"
repository = "https://github.com/my-name/my-package"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
fire = "*"
beautifulsoup4 = "^4.11.1"
requests = "*"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[tool.poetry.scripts]
mypackage = 'my_package.main:main'

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When removing the version requirement for beautifulsoup4, I encounter this error on install:

```bash
 Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in beautifulsoup4 setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[pip]+test.pypi.org

Comment: `pip3 install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple my-package==0.1.0`